# Buffers are left even when `nohidden` is set

Tags: buffers, neovim, hidden-buffers

I have explictly said in my `vimrc` that I want `nohidden` behaviour (I am jumping between files a lot, with long lasting session, and after some time buffers list is very polluted). However when I jump to other file and I run `:ls` I still see old files listed. Is there a way to prevent such behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The `'hidden'` setting

The `'hidden'`/`'nohidden'` setting tells Vim what to do about buffers that are "abandoned".

- `'hidden'` means an abandoned buffer becomes hidden (similar `:hide`).
- `'nohidden'` (the default) means the buffer is unloaded (`:bunload`).

Both `:bunload` and `:hide` do not remove a buffer from the buffer list. Therefore `'hidden'` setting will *not* affect if a buffer shows up in the buffer list.

For more help see:

```
:h abandon
:h 'hidden'
:h hidden-buffer
:h :bunload
:h :ls
```

#### Removing hidden buffers from the buffer list

To remove a buffer from the buffer list by doing `:bdelete` (unload buffer and delete from buffer list) or `:bwipeout` (really *really* get rid of the buffer).

Buffers can "automatically" be removed when they become hidden by changing the `'bufhidden'` setting on each buffer.

```
autocmd BufReadPost * set bufhidden=wipe
```

I would *not* recommend this method a it can ruin the following commands:

- Switch to the alternative buffer, `<c-^>`/`<c-6>`
- Popping back from a tag, `<c-t>`
- Moving through the jump list across buffers with `<c-i>`/`<c-o>`
- Not to mention it may interfere with some plugins which uses a temporary buffer.

#### Switching buffers

I imagine the root problem is how you navigate between buffers. I am guessing you use buffer numbers or cycle through via `:bnext`/`:bprev`. There are some alternatives to these methods.

**Behold the power of `:b`**:

- Uses `<tab>` completion
- Use `<c-d>` to list out completion
- Use partial file name. e.g. `:b foo`. Works great with `<tab>`.
- Globbing. e.g. `:b foo*bar` or `:b foo/**/bar`
- Might want to use `'hidden'` via `set hidden`
- Split variant of `:b` is `:sb`.
- Also accepts a buffer number

A common mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
```

If you like plugins you may want to check out something like [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) to switch between buffers. For more advanced file navigation use tags, cscope, [GNU global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/), or plugin like [projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist).

For more help see:

```
:h :ls
:h :b
:h 'hidden'
:h wildcard
:h c_CTRL-D
:h starstar
:h tags
:h cscope
```

#### Conclusion

Personally I would change how you switch buffers. I typically have 50+ buffers open and switch between without any issue. You can remove the occasional buffer via `:bd` or `:bw` when the need arises.

Comment: Actually I am quite heavy user of projectionist and Skim (FZF alternative) but thanks for explanation.

Comment: And also I stopped cycling through buffers as I use files instead. I often cycle through tabs as I am heavy user of NeoVim built-in terminal with Dispatch `:Start` and `:Console` command